# Eclipse freemarker template highliting

Tags: eclipse, freemarker

Eclipse Luna shows freemarker template this way:
[image]

It does not highlite any html tags inside freemarker template. Is it correct for Eclipse? May be some hidden setting is present somewhere to enable it?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the plugin (the one under JBoss Tools) doesn't know HTML highlighting. I'm also unaware of any that does that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NetBeans with this plugin:

http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/58284/freemarker-support-for-netbeans

It highlights FreeMarker and HTML markup ;-)